# non_field_errors": ["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got InMemoryUploadedFile."]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]While create the data from postman, it show this error,"image":"non_field_errors": "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got InMemoryUploadedFile."

and how to upload multiply images at onetime through ModelViewSet

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]


class ProductImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ['id', 'image']


class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    image = ProductImageSerializer(required=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        image_data = validated_data.pop('image')

        if image_data.is_valid():
            for img in image_data:
                image = ProductImage.objects.create(product=product, image=img)

        product.save()
        return product



class Product(Core):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='product')
    name = models.CharField(
        _('Product Name'),
        max_length=255,
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(30),
            MaxLengthValidator(255),
        ],
        help_text=_('Title should be Minimum 30 Characters'),
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ProductImage(Core):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename)
```

Comment: you need to send data in [product][image] key because it is nested.

Comment: send data as image[0] but same error

Comment: problem is in the formData you're passing not here

Comment: i have attach the image and i don't think there is problem in postman formData